# Connecting to lcoalhost from VM

Tags: web-server, localhost

I am using windows 10 on my local computer, and I'm building an app that requires using Linux OS, therefore I'm using an Ubuntu Virtual Box.

I installed Vagrant, and set SSH connection from my windows to my Ubuntu VM to use it's terminal from my windows terminal ("git bash" if it matters).

**Now for the issue:**

My app also has a frontend and therefore I need to connect it to a web server.
I DO NOT WANT to use the browser inside the VM, so I would like to ask if anyone knows a way to connect the app (that runs in the VM) to my local browser (chrome on my windows).

I read about ngrok, but for some reason I can't seem to make it work.

Any suggestions? Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool, rdesktop. Maybe is a solution for that you need.
Some examples here
https://www.poftut.com/linux-remote-desktop-rdesktop-command-tutorial-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the front end needs to run inside a web server, and that all runs inside the virtual Ubuntu box, yes? What you need to do is find out what IP address the virtual Ubuntu box is getting on your network, then confirm that your web server is talking to that IP address; and finally, point the browser in your Windows 10 instance at that address as well. So for instance, if the Ubuntu box is pulling `192.168.0.186` from your DHCP server, you need to confirm that its web server is listening to `192.168.0.186`, and then point your Windows 10 browser at `http:\\192.168.0.186\`.